# how to organize this code and add some validation

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out how to organize the following piece of code so i can add a few validations for a form:

```
<?php

//Calculo em php 
$valor_final = 1320 - 1.2 * $_POST['val1'];
$valor_confiscado = $_POST['val1'] - $valor_final;
$valor_total = $valor_confiscado + $valor_confiscado;

$valor_final1 = "<div class=info><span class=style1>Parcela do subsidio de Férias/Natal que fica para o trabalhador ou aposentado:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_final Euros</span></div><br><br>";
$valor_confiscado1 = "<div class=error><span class=style1>Parcela do subsidio de Férias/Natal que o governo confisca:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_confiscado Euros</span></div>";
$valor_total1 = "<div class=error><span class=style1>Parcela dos 2 subsidios juntos (Natal e Férias) confiscado pelo governo:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_total Euros</span></div>";

//Resultados
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
    echo $valor_final1;
    echo $valor_confiscado1;
    echo $valor_total1;
}
?>
```

Before I echo the 3 variables I would like to check if the value inserted on the textbox `$_POST['val1']` is less than 600 and greater than 1100, if so i would like to echo other msg instead of the $valor_final etc...
As you can see I have a if statment that checks if the page is getting hit by post form, so it can hide the message if nothing has been submited by the user, I would like to keep it or a better solution for this.

This is the best example for what i need:

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") || ($_POST['val1'] < 600)) 
{ echo $toolow;}
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") || $_POST['val1'] > 1100)) 
{ echo $toohigh;}
elseif (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    echo $valor_final1;
    echo $valor_confiscado1;
    echo $valor_total1;
}
```

Im trying to do this by my own since 2 days ago, but i got tired :S

Edit:

I did this:

```
<?php
$valor_final = 1320 - 1.2 * $_POST['val1'];
$valor_confiscado = $_POST['val1'] - $valor_final;
$valor_total = $valor_confiscado + $valor_confiscado;
if ($_POST['val1'] <= 600);{
echo "<div class=error><span class=style1>O governo não pretende confiscar subsidios inferiores a 600 euros:</span></div>";
exit; 
}
if ($_POST['val1'] >= 1100);{
echo "<div class=error><span class=style1>O governo não pretende confiscar subsidios inferiores a 1100 euros:</span></div>";
exit; 
}
else {
echo "<div class=info><span class=style1>Parcela do subsidio de Férias/Natal que fica para o trabalhador ou aposentado:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_final Euros</span></div><br><br>";
echo "<div class=error><span class=style1>Parcela do subsidio de Férias/Natal que o governo confisca:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_confiscado Euros</span></div>";
echo "<div class=error><span class=style1>Parcela dos 2 subsidios juntos (Natal e Férias) confiscado pelo governo:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_total Euros</span></div>";
}

?>
```

And it trowns me this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/terrachat/domains/terrachat.com.pt/public_html/projectos/calcular_work.php on line 139

```
**Line 137 exit; 
Line 138 }
Line 139 else {
Line 140 echo "<div class=info><span class=style1>Parcela do subsidio de Férias/Natal que fica para o trabalhador ou aposentado:</span> <span class=style2>$valor_final Euros</span></div><br><br>";**
```

Can someone please help with this?

Sincerely

Comment: Could you highlight line 137,138,139,140 for us?

Comment: Also it is good practice to use names (for variables, functions, class ...) and comments in English.

Comment: Thanks for reply, ok my bad i will follow your advice next time, please check my initial post i have higlighted those 3 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 135 you have

```
if ($_POST['val1'] >= 1100);{
```

while it should be

```
if ($_POST['val1'] >= 1100) {
```

Also in line 131 you have

```
if ($_POST['val1'] <= 600);{
```

while it should be

```
if ($_POST['val1'] <= 600) {
```

Usually `unexpected T_(*)` means that you are missing some `{`, `}`, `;`, `,` or you are adding too much of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add those lines:

```
if ($_POST['val1'] < 600 || $_POST['val1'] > 1100) {
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks M42 i tryed something like that but trow me an error, because i cant make it work with the rest of the code :S

Comment: @DaniQueiroga: Update your question with the code including those lines and show us what is the error message.

Comment: sorry i dint expressed well, it dint trow any error, it just dint worked the way it should. the code i posted it shows those 3 variables at the end, and i want to add an if statment for example: if the number is less than 600 then will show a message and not the variables i have now, if the number is grater than 1100 then will show another message and willl not show the variables i have now.... do you know what i mean?

Comment: This is the best example for what i need: 
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") || ($_POST['val1'] < 600)) 
{ echo $toolow;}
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") || $_POST['val1'] > 1100)) 
{ echo $toohigh;}
elseif (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    echo $valor_final1;
    echo $valor_confiscado1;
    echo $valor_total1;
}

Im trying to do this by my own since 2 days ago, but i got tired :S